# Allow a property of a data class to only accept certain values

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, data-class

Some context first. In Android using Kotlin, changing the visibility is done like in the following.

```
myView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Setting any other `Int` value other than `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE` returns an error.

Now I have a Kotlin data class that accepts a constructor parameter `flag` of type `Int`.

How do I implement this the same way in my Kotlin code such that `myClass.flag = Flag.A` and no other value?

Comment: Have your `init` block or something else (e.g., `newInstance()` factory function) check to see if `flag` is a valid value and throw some sort of exception (e.g., `IllegalArgumentException`) if it is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same warning behaviour as you get for `View.visibility` constants, you'll need to write a lint check for it. Here's a couple of blogs about doing that sort of thing:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-custom-lint-checks-in-android/

https://medium.com/@vanniktech/writing-your-first-lint-check-39ad0e90b9e6

If you want to enforce a type, then like people have said enums are a way to go, or you could use a sealed class:

```
sealed class Flag {
    object A : Flag()
    object B : Flag()
}
```

or just throw in a `require` check in the `init` block with a list of valid constants, handle it at runtime!

Answer (score 4):

probably by just defining it as an enum

```
enum view{
  GONE=0,
  VISIBLE=1,
  INVISIBLE=2,
}

class MyView{
  Public view visibility { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yeah seems like Kotlin does not support `IntDef` or `IntRange` yet so `enum`s are the way to go. Java supports the `IntDef` and `IntRange` and this is how `setVisibiltiy` works FYI